# Broadcast receiver intent not received until phone unlocked

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to start an activity with the phone locked. I have a receiver class for things such as

```
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

I've added my own intent action such as "my.app.name.dothis", registered it, and added it to my receiver class.

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("my.app.name.dothis"))
    {
        Log.d("mytag", "here");
    }
```

My foreground service notification has the pending intent of this action:

```
    Intent startThis = new Intent("my.app.name.dothis");
    PendingIntent startPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, startThis, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

When I click the notification while locked it does nothing, as soon as I unlock the broadcast is received and I log "here". How can I receive the broadcast while locked?

Comment: in which android version you try to get the broadcast ?

Comment: @Harin   I'm testing using android 8